# Flexslider's arrows is like a cut bottom. What to do?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

What can i do for normal arrows?

[image: cutting bottom of arrows]
cutting bottom of arrows

Flexslider from http://flexslider.woothemes.com/
[image: Flexslider with normal arrows]
Flexslider with normal arrows

Site adress http://artkrasnodar.ru/cardiolt/ - on latest Twitter Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick fix CSS solution:

```
.flex-direction-nav a {
    heigth: 45px;
}
```

Here is a long-term solution:

```
   $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        },
        prevText: '<span class="flex-custom-nav-button--left"></i>',
        nextText: '<spam class="flex-custom-nav-button---right"></i>';
      });
    });
```

And then you migh style the buttons as you wish, by using `.flex-custom-nav-button--left` and `.flex-custom-nav-button---right`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I just change 'font-size' in flexslider.css from 40px to 36px